# How exactly is the magnitude of a vector of non-orthonormal basis calculated intuitively?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'll preface this question by stating that I am a beginner of sorts to the concept of vectors, and even more so for linear algebra in general.

From what I understand, for some given vector $(1,2)$, the magnitude for said vector for basis $\hat i $ and $\hat j$, in my textbook from my highschool I am studying from,  is given as the square root of the square of the components, 1 and 2. I can tell how it intuitively makes sense, taking into account how this vector in question can be decomposed into vectors that solely point along the basis , which with the vector itself, forms a right-angle triangle. Pythagoras's theorem leads the way for the rest

From what I figured, finding the components of my original vector along either of the basis vectors is as simple as projecting over them.

How would I find the magnitude for such a vector belonging to a non-orthonormal basis however (I'd prefer to understand it for a two-dimensional case for simplicity)? I'd explored a video about 'metric tensors', a particular matrix-like object from what I understand, that did the job of finding the magnitude given any general basis vector, from what little I could glean from it. However, I was left even more confused towards the end, since I couldn't quite understand how they worked. They'd also explained that the Pythagorean Law-based formula of finding the magnitude only works for basis vectors that are orthonormal

Here is what I assume the diagram for a vector of  some basis vectors, $\vec e1, \vec e2$ would look like:
[image]

The blue lines denote the decompositions along either basis
I can sort of tell why the Pythagoras-based formula to find the magnitude wouldn't work here.
The decomposition of the vector along $\vec e1$ does give me an accurate idea of HOW much of the vector is along $\vec e1$. But with the projection of the vector along $\vec e2$, something seems to be wrong

On second thought, something about my entire approach in of itself seems to be dreadfully wrong. I can't put my finger on what about it exactly that I am doing wrong

Even if I assume that I find the projections along either basis correctly, I am not sure how to move forward. I can't seem to think about how I could find the magnitude intuitively even if the projections along each basis vector were provided

I am sure I am getting something wrong. How exactly can one intuitively find the magnitude of some vector with respect to such orthonormal basis?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\brak}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}$Two snags that may explain why something seems wrong are:

1. A vector space need not be a Cartesian space. For example, the set of polynomials of degree at most five on the interval $[-1, 1]$ is a real vector space of dimension six. Or, a plane tangent to a surface in Euclidean three-space may be viewed as a two-dimensional real vector space, but it has no natural choice of basis so we can't view its elements naturally as ordered pairs.
2. The concept of *length* comes from *additional structure that must be chosen*, such as a "norm" or an "inner product."

A norm is a type of axiomization of length of vectors. Knowing the lengths of basis vectors in a normed vector space, however, does not determine the lengths of linear combinations. A "normed vector space" is therefore not sufficient to support the question as formulated.

By contrast, an inner product is an axiomization of the Euclidean dot product, and as a mathematical setting is (probably) implicitly what you had in mind when writing the question. The concept of an *orthonormal basis* only makes sense in an inner product space, a real vector space equipped with an inner product.

Precisely, an *inner product* on a real vector space $(V, +, \cdot)$ is a real-valued function $\brak{\ ,\ }$ on ordered paris of vectors satisfying the following axioms:

- (Symmetry) $\brak{v, u} = \brak{u, v}$ for all $u$, $v$ in $V$;
- (Bilinearity) $\brak{cu + v,w} = c\brak{u, w} + \brak{v, w}$ for all $u$, $v$, $w$ in $V$ and all real $c$;
- (Positive-definiteness) $\brak{v, v} \geq 0$ for all $v$ in $V$, with equality if and only if $v = 0$.

The *length* of a vector $v$ in an inner product space is defined to be $\|v\| = \sqrt{\brak{v, v}}$. If $(e_{j})_{j=1}^{n}$ is a basis of $V$ and $v = \sum_{j} v_{j} e_{j}$, then bilinearity guarantees
$$
\brak{v, v} = \sum_{j,k=1}^{n} v_{j} v_{k} \brak{e_{j}, e_{k}}.
$$
That formula (or really, its square root) is the answer to the question.

If the basis $(e_{j})$ is orthonormal, then $\brak{e_{j}, e_{k}} = \delta_{jk}$ is $1$ if $j = k$ and $0$ otherwise. In that situation, $\|v\| = \sqrt{\sum_{j} v_{j}^{2}}$, a generalized Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: So the inner product is a generalized equation that allows us to compute the dot product for any given basis? Is there an intuitive way to understand why exactly it allows us to find the length? I am struggling to understand it.

Comment: It's more that _an_ inner product is a function that allows us to _define_ length. Any introductory book on linear algebra should provide detailed explanations. There are good free ebooks in the [AMS Open Math Notes](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes) series.

Comment: I've done quite a bit of reading into the subject. While I understand what a norm and inner product are for , and the axioms you've specified, I can't quite understand why the norm of a vector $v$ is defined as the square root of $⟨v,v⟩$. Is there a specific reason as to why it is defined as such? What about the root of the inner product of a vector on itself allows for us to generalize the notion of a length/norm?

Comment: For the ordinary dot product in the plane, $(x_1,y_1)\cdot(x_2,y_2)=x_1x_2 + y_1y_2$, the square root of the dot product of a vector $v=(x,y)$ with itself is the Pythagorean length: $|v|=\sqrt{v\cdot v}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The axioms for a norm or for an inner product are chosen to generalize the Euclidean dot product and the Euclidean norm, and their relationship. (If it matters, there are norms that are not induced by an inner product. But this may be getting far afield of your question.)

Comment: But this seems like it'd only work if $(x1,y1)$ and $(x2,y2)$ were with respect to an orthogonal basis. If the components of my vector $v$ was with respect to the basis $e1,e2$ in my post,  how would the root of the dot product of $v$ with itself yield the Euclidean length/norm?

Comment: You're right; the deeper point is that _length_ of vectors isn't an intrinsically-defined concept, but _extra structure_ we impose on the plane (or on a "real vector space" more generally). If we have components of a vector with respect to a non-orthogonal basis, the length will depend on the dot products of the basis vectors with each other as in the displayed equation of the answer.